# custom disk partitioning using clients in sccm 2012r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, wds, sccm-2012

I'm using sccm2012r2 to deploy OS on clients.
every thing is OK .but after installation completed I realized that SCCM partitioned disk and deleted all previous data.
my question is that how to config task sequence to ask user to partitioning the disk and select custom partition to install the OS .
thanks

Comment: You want to install an OS w/out wiping the disk? What have you tried, where are you having trouble?

Comment: I need to let users select their own partition for windows installation in it.without touching other drives in their pc .

Answer (score 0):

SCCM wasn't designed for one off configurations where each user selects their own configuration, in this case a partition scheme. It's power comes from being able to massively configure workstations/servers from a single point, filter and configure those same assets based on a breadth of parameters, so on and so on.

Note that I didn't say it wasn't possible. It most certainly is, you will have to get someone to develop a custom app (I would do it in .NET) that ties into your task sequence, and sets a couple of variables based on user input. Either that, or the custom app actually formats the machine for them and sets the variable for where Windows should be installed, perhaps using Powershell or DiskPart on the back end. I won't go into detail about it here, as it's something that can't be explained in a single SE answer, and it would essentially be a back and forth between us.

Comment: I made a deployment wizard using UDI .and in there I specified that user select which drive to install the OS .there was a check box in the bottom of that step of wizard "clean the selected volume".that's OK.But during deployment it changed to "format and partition disk 0".I couldn't understand how it's possible.
all I want to do is deploying OS through SCCM2012r2 and Let user to select where to install OS .or format and partition the disk if they want .just like simple WDS.
is it possible?
I checked disk partition variables but undertood nothing.

Comment: Then why use SCCM instead of WDS?